# How to enter 3.Plane chars of the Neo2 keyboard layout in emacs running on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, emacs, keyboard-layout, karabiner

I've got a problem on OS X with emacs, Karabiner and the [Neo2 keyboard layout](https://neo-layout.org) a alternativ German keyboard layout.
The third and fifth keyboard plane entert with Capslock as mod key is not working.

My keyboard layout of choice is Neo2, I set it up, on the Mac im switching to, using [jgosmanns neo2-layout-osx](https://github.com/jgosmann/neo2-layout-osx) from GitHub in combination with the suggested [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and it's rules enabled.

On other Editors like TextEdit the fist 5 planes are working correctly,
but on emacs the 3. and the 5. plane are not. I assume emacs uses somehow the Capslock key. Perhaps there is a similar thing to `(setq ns-right-alternate-modifier 'none)` which is needed to type characters like `~` or `@` on a regular german keyboard layout.

Or there is a problem between Karabiner and emacs, since Karabiner is needed to enter the third, fifth and sixth plane of Neo2 on OS X.

A minimal init.el:

```
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)

(setq mac-function-modifier 'control
  mac-control-modifier 'control
  mac-option-modifier 'alt
  mac-command-modifier 'meta
  ns-right-alternate-modifier 'none)
```

How can I enable at least the 3. plane for the needed chars:

`…_[]^!<>=& \/{}*?()-:@ #$|~+%"';`

Answer (score 3):

To make it work on a recent Apple Silicon MacbookPro with Emacs.app 27.2 it required setting only:

```lisp
(setq mac-option-modifier 'none)
```

Otherwise the Mod3 keys would be recognized as Meta keys.

Comment: Also works with emacs-plus@28

Comment: Note: I needed the other settings from the question as well to get a usable editor.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following configuration option to Emacs did the trick for me:

```
  (setq ns-right-alternate-modifier nil)
  (setq ns-alternate-modifier 'meta)
  (global-set-key (kbd " ") " ")
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me.